# How to Get the Title of a SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, office365

I am trying to retrieve a list from SharePoint using the web services. I ran into the problem described in [this blog post](http://mqsharepoint.blogspot.com/2008/10/working-with-sharepoint-web-services.html), i.e. the GetList method apparently expects to be passed the list's title instead of the list's name (even though the parameter is called "listName"). I have the list's name, but I cannot figure out how to get the list's title. Where can I find that?

I'm using the SharePoint in Office 365, which I believe is 2010.

Answer (score 1):

A little over head but try this code. Its just a sample code, you might want to mould it to your logic.

```
string listName = "MyList";

Lists.Lists listSvc = new Lists.Lists();
listSvc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(listSvc.GetListCollection().OuterXml);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("A", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/");

XmlNode requiredList = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//A:List[contains(@DefaultViewUrl,'" + listName + "')]", nsmgr);
string listTitle = requiredList.Attributes["Title"].Value;

XmlNode list = listSvc.GetList(listTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

strListName: Can be either a list name, such as "Documents", or a GUID of the list, with or without curly braces, in the following format:

{318B9E8F-1EF4-4D49-9773-1BD2976772B6}

[you may find more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd964182%28v=office.12%29) - the above info is an excerpt from this document